# Python Problema con islice y writerow en csv

Tags: python, csv

soy muy nuevo en esta plataforma, en python y en programación en general...aunque es algo a lo que le tengo muchas ganas y estoy en ello, de antemano pido disculpas por mi desconocimiento... 
Voy al problema, tengo un csv en el que las 3 primeras líneas no se corresponden con el encabezado por lo que quiero eliminarlas para quedarme con los datos que realmente me interesan, tras un par de semanas de investigación (partiendo de 0) he conseguido hacerlo con islice pero... el archivo csv que obtengo no me coloca los datos en las correspondientes filas sino en una sola fila.

```
import csv
from itertools import islice


archivo= open("Alia_Puerto_Rey.csv", 'r')
lee= csv.reader(archivo)
limita = islice(lee, 3, 28)

with open ('limita.csv', 'w') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f)
    w.writerow(limita)
```

Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda, la que me deis ahora y la que ya me habeis ido dando al leer las dudas anteriores.

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio y a la programación en general :) Iría bien una muestra del archivo. No hace falta que sean los datos reales, pero sí que sean representativos. Por cierto, ¿sabes que existe `next(f)` para saltar una línea? Con tres de ellos empezarías a leer en la línea 4.

Comment: Gracias fedorqui, no conocia next(f). Despues de leer varios foros y demás al final llegué a islice y por eso lo utilicé. El archivo es este (http://www.aemet.es/es/eltiempo/observacion/ultimosdatos_4478X_datos-horarios.csv?k=ext&l=4478X&datos=det&w=0&f=temperatura&x=). Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que usas `writerrow` en vez de `writerrows`, el primero espera una cadena y si no lo es llama al método `str` del objeto y lo escribe como fila. El segundo espera un iterable en el que cada item es una fila en cambio.

Tu le pasas el contenido del archivo completo a `islice`, recibe un iterador con cada fila como una lista, simplemente descartará los tres primeros caracteres y luego genera un iterable que va retornando lista a lista (linea a linea). Como usas `writerow` primero consume el iterable obtenido una lista de listas y luego llama al método `__str__` del objeto (de la lista de listas) obteniendo algo como:

```
"['Texto_Fila3_Col0', 'Texto_Fila3_Col1', ...]","['Texto_Fila4_Col0', 'Texto_Fila3_Col1', ...]", ..."
```

luego coge la cadena y la escribe como una sola fila.

Debes usar `writerrows` en su lugar, en este caso iterara sobre el iterable de `islice` y tratará cada item como una fila:

```
import csv
from itertools import islice


with open("Alia_Puerto_Rey.csv") as in_file, open('limita.csv', 'w') as out_file:
    reader = csv.reader(in_file)
    writer = csv.writer(out_file)
    reader_slice = islice(reader, 3, None)
    writer.writerows(reader_slice)
```

Cuando necesites que se itere hasta el final, usa `None` como valor para `stop`, así no tienes que hardcodear y se adaptará a cualquier iterable sin que necesites conocer su longitud.

Dicho esto, si no vas  modificar nada de cada fila ni modificar el delimitador, carácter de acotado, etc, parsear el csv para solo descartar las tres primeras filas es una perdida de recursos. Lee el fichero simplemente, sin parsear las filas, descarta las tres primeras y escribe el resto tal cual en el de salida.

Por otro lado, como comenta @fedorqui, puedes usar `next(iterador)` para consumir un item del mismo. Si lo llamas tres veces el iterador sobre el archivo consumirá las tres primeras líneas. `itertool.islice` es muy útil en ciertas situaciones, especialmente combinado el parámetro `step`, pero para este caso no aporta mucho realmente.

```
with open("Alia_Puerto_Rey.csv") as in_file, open('limita.csv', 'w') as out_file:
    for _ in range(3):
        next(in_file)
    out_file.writelines(in_file)
```

Comment: Muy buena respuesta. Yo suelo usar `csv.DictReader`, pues permite más control "de serie" sobre las líneas que vas leyendo

Comment: Si, yo si voy a manipular el csv (aparte de Pandas y demás) prefiero `DictReader` también,. Acceder a las filas mediante indizado con `reader` (`row[23]`) es menos legible y yo personalmente tiendo a perderme como el csv tenga bastantes columnas y soy muy vago para andar contando... : ) `row['nombre de columna 23']` es más simple y legible, además desde Py3.8 retorna un diccionario estándar (ordenado), la sobrecarga con respecto a `reader` es menos significativa (antes retornaba un diccionario (sin orden lo que en algunos casos era un problema) y en 3.6 un `OrderedDict`).

Comment: Anda, no sabía del cambio en Py3.8. No entiendo lo de _diccionario estándar (ordenado)_, ¿en qué se diferencia de un OrderedDict?

Comment: A partir de Python 3.7 los diccionarios mantienen el orden de inserción de las claves como característica del lenguaje, ya no son colecciones desordenadas como sigue siendo `set`. Es decir se comportan como `OrderedDict`, de hecho (no he hecho test en 3.8 pero en eran más eficientes que OrderedDict). De hecho ha habido discusiones de si hay o no que eliminar `collections.OrderedDict` de la stdlib, se mantiene por retrocompatibilidad principalmente y porque tiene dos métodos que pueden ser útiles (`popitem` y `move_to_end`), aunque se podrían implementar en la clase `dict`.

Comment: Esto hace que tanto en la stdlib como en muchos paquetes externos se esté cambiando  `OrderdDcit ` por  `dict ` sin más, cuyo uso será cada vez más marginal. Lo mejor es que a pesar de mantener el orden son considerablemente más eficientes que la antigua implementación. Esto a veces es muy útil, por ejemplo volviendo a los csv, puedes conseguir las celdas de una fila sin desordenar llamando a `row.values()`. Además en Python3.8 se puede usar `reversed()` sobre `dict` y sus vistas, una de las ventajas de la nueva implementación.

Comment: Qué bueno, realmente hay casos en los que esto sí es útil, me alegra que se haya incorporado en el `dict` "original", el builtin. Muchas gracias por la explicación, FJSevilla.

Comment: Muchas gracias, evidentemente así si sale!!! Desconocía totalmente next(iterador), mira que he intentado documentarme pero no habia visto esa orden por ningún sitio. Otra cosa mas que me llevo. Gracias.